# Photo grid seem doesn't fit properly

Tags: html, css

i have some issues with photo grid.
its like have a padding on right side, i have put rule like padding-right 0
or margin-right or right 0 and still see the issues.

[doesnt fit properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ppjov.png)

here my workaround https://codepen.io/RIN-id/pen/ZrzyZB

> index.html

```
<ul id="photo-gallery">


    <li>
        <a href="a.jpg" data-description=" Mulak Mar-onan (Kapal Tuktuk)"> 
                          <img src="img/galery/a.jpg" > 
                        </a>
    </li>




</ul>
```

> styles.css

```
 #photos {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}

#photo-gallery {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;

  /*! overflow-x: scroll; */
}
  h3 {font-size: 20px; color: #fff;}

#photos img {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 2px;

}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  max-width: 780px;
  text-align: left;
}

#overlay {
  background: rgba(0,0,0, .8);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 5000;
}

#overlay img {
  margin: 10% auto 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 5000;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 113px;
}
```

thank you, sorry for bad grammar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try to set
margin: 0; padding: 0

top: 0;
bot: 0;

Comment: This answer is a straight copy of funderjimed ieinc's answer and doesn't add any new information

Answer (score 0):

try put margin: 0; padding: 0 in your css

Comment: seem still the same sir

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the images are each 30% width floated left with only a small margin that doesn't offset the 10% gap left over.

What I would do:
-Delete margin for #photos img
-Change width to 33.33%
-Add desired padding (2px for instance)
-Add `box-sizing: border-box` to include padding in width